# CSS gray text opacity and Firefox color issue

Tags: css, firefox, opacity

I'm using following jQuery function to change the opacity of text (it's color: #999999)

```
$('.small_buttons').css('opacity', 0.3);
```

The effect looks good in Chrome or even Internet Explorer 8, but in current version of Firefox (3.6.10) this text gets really strange greenish colour, instead of nice pale gray.

Screenshots:

Chrome:

[image: http://imgur.com/eTlAg.png]

Firefox:

[image: http://imgur.com/QAOF0.png]

Help appreciated!

Update:
example: http://jsfiddle.net/YnDFr/1/

Comment: That's weird. Could you provide a link to your page for testing? Are you sure you don't have custom colors activated in FF? Tools > Options > Content > Colors > "Allow pages..." should be checked for correct colors.

Comment: I can't get this to happen with very minimal code. Can you show us what you're using? http://jsfiddle.net/YnDFr/

Comment: you can see this effect if you add the text color :#999999 to the div http://jsfiddle.net/YnDFr/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears it's because the element has no background, or specified as transparent. Try to add it the same background as its container.

Comment: Yes, that works! After adding the #fff background-color it renders fine. Is it a known Firefox bug? In my case it's OK to add solid background to the container, but what if I wanted to render it in transparent div (and the image background would be from some element several level above in DOM tree)?

Answer (score 2):

fyi: I had the same issue with FF 3.6, found the following solution, which actually works on a variety of browsers excl. IE < 9.0;

just use the following syntax: **`color: rgba(r,g,b,opacity);`**

i.e:  **`color: rgba( 153, 153, 153, .5) ;`**

this results in **`color: #999999;`** and **`opacity: .5;`**
no need to apply background-color if you're text is on a transparent DIV. Most modern browsers, even IE 9.0 have support for the RGBA() color definition

Comment: Yep, you're right, using rgba indeed doesn't cause this issue in FF 3.6 (although not being able to use `$('selector').css('opacity','');` makes some things more problematic). FF 4 doesn't have this problem at all, so soon we we'll be able to forget about it. Thanks.